# select query with partitioned timestamps

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, timestamp

I want to select count(*) from table for a 12 hours period and separate results by a time period like this:

```
time          | count
00:00 - 03:00 | 12
03:00 - 06:00 | 25
etc...
```

i wrote something like:

```
select
    timestamp,
    row_number() over (partition by timestamp order by count(*) desc) as score
from logs
where to_timestamp(timestamp) between symmetric now() and now() - interval '12 hours'
group by timestamp
order by score desc;
```

but it separates on every timestamp record:

```
timestamp      | score
1466330486.813 | 25
```

how to unite time periods correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with a simple group by and a date function if you're comfortable with per-hour resolution:

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('hour', timestamp),
  count(*) as score
FROM logs
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', timestamp);
```

The `date_trunc` documentation [is here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html). If you need custom time periods (like three-hour chunks, or three-hour chunks relative to the current timestamp), then you can write a custom function to calculate that, and handle it in the same fashion.